# PostgreSQL Common Table Expressions vs a temporary table?

Tags: postgresql

The [PostgreSQL documentation on WITH](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/queries-with.html) shows the following example:

```
WITH regional_sales AS (
        SELECT region, SUM(amount) AS total_sales
        FROM orders
        GROUP BY region
     ), top_regions AS (
        SELECT region
        FROM regional_sales
        WHERE total_sales > (SELECT SUM(total_sales)/10 FROM regional_sales)
     )
SELECT region,
       product,
       SUM(quantity) AS product_units,
       SUM(amount) AS product_sales
FROM orders
WHERE region IN (SELECT region FROM top_regions)
GROUP BY region, product;
```

It also notes:

> A useful property of WITH queries is that they are evaluated only once
>   per execution of the parent query, even if they are referred to more
>   than once by the parent query or sibling WITH queries.

I see that `WITH` can be used for other things, like recursive evaluation. But **in the example above, is there any important difference between using `WITH` and creating temporary tables?**

Comment: when you use CTE for building up the query, adding another column to `SELECT` in `WITH` is just typing the name and rerunning. While with temporary table it would take `DROP` and `CREATE`. On the other hand if you build a query and you going to reuse static data lots of times - building temporary table with indexes is definitely beneficial against CTE.

Comment: @VaoTsun if using `TEMPORARY TABLE` with `ON COMMIT DROP` within a query, it's also just a matter of modifying the query and re-running, right? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createtable.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are a few subtle differences, but nothing drastic:

- You can add indexes on a temp table;
- Temp tables exist for the life of the session (or, if `ON COMMIT DROP`, transaction), wheras `WITH` is always scoped strictly to the query;
- If a query invokes a function/procedure, it can see the temp table, but it can *not* see any `WITH` table-expressions;
- A temp table generates `VACUUM` work on the system catalogs that `WITH` doesn't, it needs an extra round trip to create/fill it, and it requires extra work in the server's cache management, so it's slightly less efficient.

Overall, you should prefer `WITH` to temp tables unless you know you will benefit from creating an index.

However, the other option, a subquery in the `FROM` clause, has a very different set of advantages. It can be inlined, in particular, and qualifiers can be pulled up / pushed down. I wrote about this in [a recent blog article](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/).

Comment: What about views and temporary views?

Comment: Kinda inbetween but closer to a temp table than a CTE term. No indexes. Session scoped. Visible to functions/procedures. Needs catalog vacuum.

Comment: @CraigRinger The blog article seems to be outdated.  Since PG12, CTEs are no longer optimization fences.